# Query the DynamoDb using a nested attribute ID

Tags: nosql, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table and items in the table that look something like this:

```
{
   "id":"id",
   "randomData":{
      "randomData1":"randomData1",
      "randomData2":"randomData2"
   },
   "status":"status",
   "subTasks":[
      {
         "subTaskId":"subTaskId",
         "subTaskType":"subType",
         "subTaskAnyData":"subTaskAnyData",
         "subTaskStatus":"status",
      },
      {
         "subTaskId":"subTaskId",
         "subTaskType":"subType",
         "subTaskAnyData":"subTaskAnyData",
         "subTaskStatus":"status",
      },
      {
         "subTaskId":"subTaskId",
         "subTaskType":"subType",
         "subTaskAnyData":"subTaskAnyData",
         "subTaskStatus":"status",
      }
   ]
}
```

So I have the top-level **id** (primary / partition key) attribute, but also inside the subTasks array, there is the **subTaskId**.

Is there an efficient way to query the table and get the data i.e. the one subTask object based on subTaskId?

Or should I consider redesigning the table and having the subtasks in a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

In short,

No it's over kill, because you must get the full object or/and perform a lot of scans.

It's depend of what many times you request the subTaskId, **you may use a separate** table or perform a monotable with another **GSI** (subTaskId as Secondary Index) with queries as much efficient than scans.

Comment: Thanks Hatim!
I would probably need the specific subtask often enough, checking the status, retry etc.
Not sure I understand the monotable approach, and subTaskId as secondary index since I'll always have multiple subtasks?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can use like a monotable to store all your data. you need to simulate all types of request to design it perfectly like ( get task by Taskid, get subtask by SubTask id, get all subtaskd by Taskid) ==> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html

Comment: I've found [this tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) to be helpful when trying to visualize a table design around certain access patterns